# What is this field in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that contains both the real and complex numbers called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, quaternions, number-systems, hypercomplex-numbers

Note: this question is wrong – this is not a field, though it is not obvious why it wouldn't be.

---

So, I (first year undergraduate mathematics student) was looking around the internet and found an [interesting enough piece of C++](https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/keskustelu/31979-cpp-recomplex). It contained the definition of something they called a 'recomplex' number so I'm assuming it's some kind of hypercomplex construction, which it appears to be. It also obeys the field axioms and both the reals and the complex numbers are its subsets and closed under its operations. With fair warning that it is the work of a well-known man of many failures and delusions of grandeur, I went ahead and tested out the field axioms he was claiming it fulfilled.

In all simplicity for any numbers $x = (a,i,j,k), y = (b,l,m,n) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, their addition is normal vector addition $x+y = (a+b, i+l, j+m, k+n)$, but their multiplication is defined by
$$xy = (a b - i l - j n - k m, a l + b i + j m - k n, a m + b j - i n - k l, a n + b k + i m + j l).$$

This can also be derived from the following multiplication table for basis vectors

| $\cdot$ | $1$ | $i$ | $j$ | $k$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $1$ | $i$ | $j$ | $k$ |
| $i$ | $i$ | $-1$ | $k$ | $-j$ |
| $j$ | $j$ | $k$ | $i$ | $-1$ |
| $k$ | $k$ | $-j$ | $-1$ | $-i$ |

Multiplication and addition are obviously commutative and associative,
and the multiplication obviously simplifies to vector scalar multiplication if only the real component has a non-zero value. Similarly having only the first two components with a non-zero value in both numbers gives you the definition of complex multiplication.

Additive and multiplicative identity obviously exist as per the previous paragraph and are the same as for the reals. Additive inverses are similarly obvious.

Multiplicative inverses are tricky but can be derived. The components of a multiplicative inverse are in order
$$\frac{a\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)+i\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)}{\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)^2+\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)^2},$$
$$\frac{-a\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)+i\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)}{\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)^2+\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)^2},$$
$$\frac{-j\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)-k\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)}{\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)^2+\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)^2}, \text{and}$$
$$\frac{j\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)-k\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)}{\left(a^2-i^2+2jk\right)^2+\left(2ai-j^2+k^2\right)^2}.$$
I have symbolically simplified multiplying by this and it does in fact give us $(1,0,0,0)$.

On top of all that, I've symbolically went and confirmed that distributivity is also obeyed. That may all be wrong in the end, as I did it quite tired and with rather simplistic tools. If anyone cares to check the work, it's in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JuhaJGamer/4decae12ab6b0640a4e8697edea233c6)

That kind of suggests that we have here a field which is also the 4-dimensional real vector space. **My question is specifically what this (or this kind of, if this is one of many) field is called in mathematics?** I was (and still am) under the impression that such a neat extension of the complex numbers should not be possible, as this doesn't seem to follow the pattern of dropping more and more properties as the dimension increases as seen in the Cayley-Dickson algebras. Quaternions for example have non-commutative multiplication.

EDIT: As suspected, it isn't a field. It's very nearly a field, but there are extra non-invertible numbers as found by John Palmieri. Crackpots are still crackpots and have not suddenly found something mathematically revolutionary. The complexity of inverting the numbers lured me into using a computational tool which did not check whether certain algebraic manipulations were exactly legal.

Comment: Check your table and commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: It looks like (up to possible typos) the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Comment: @TedShifrin I should do that. The table is derived from a comment in the code from a known crackpot who uses it as an example of what his recursive algorithm can generate.

Comment: Note that $ik \neq ki$ so it is not commutative. The Cayley-Dickson construction can be used to extend the reals to the complex number, the complex to quaternions, quaternions to the octonions, and the octonions to sedenions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction

Comment: @CyclotomicField Seems there was more a problem with the table than with the operation. Running it in Python, the definition seems commutative for all pairs of basis vectors, the table was just off due to bad handwriting and tiredness.

Comment: $(1, 1, \sqrt{2}, 0)$ is not invertible.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri That has to be it. This was the issue [last time](https://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/keskustelu/16900-2d-algebra#v132717) he tried as well. In short, there was a "zero line" which wasn't invertible instead of just zero which made it useless as a number system. Seems that's the case now as well. SymPy obviously didn't catch it because it wasn't meant to. Was it not five in the morning for me I hope I would have seen it as well. I suspected as much, as I said in the question.

Comment: Indeed, in your formula for the inverse of an element, you should take special care to look for instances where you're dividing by zero.

Comment: The Frobenius theorem proves that the only finite dimensional division algebras over the reals are the real numbers, complex numbers and quaternions. So any commutative multiplication table they scheme up will fail to be a field. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: To be clear: quaternions were found centuries ago by William Rowan Hamilton who knew that they do not commute and who was not a crackpot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the vulgar language ("crackpot").

Answer (score 3):

Here is another reason this algebra is not a field (aside from the Frobenius theorem and undefined inverses): according to CAS computations, it has two nontrivial idempotents, namely $(1/2,0,\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}},\mp\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}})$, and so is isomorphic to $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

This is isomorphic to tessarines (reals extended with complex and split-complex unities).

Let denote your $j$ as $J$ and your $k$ as $K$. At the same time, let denote the split-complex unity as $j$. Then $J$ and $K$ can be expressed as:

$J={(-1)}^{1/4} j$ and $K={(-1)}^{3/4} j.$

Now you can see that all your multiplication table holds.